# How can i get image Uri when i load image by url using Glide image loading library

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Here is my Code

```
 Glide.with(context).load(Config.USER_PROFILE_IAMGE_PATH + response).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Uri imageUri=???????
                    return true;
                }
            }).into(holder.senderImageHolder);
```

I am trying to load image from url and it is showing properly. Now I want to show same image into different activity. so I need image uri

Comment: Why don't you pass `Config.USER_PROFILE_IAMGE_PATH + response` url to the next activity

Comment: Why you need URL you can load this image any where in activity

Comment: This will again load image from url but i do not want this